# Complex Fourier series of a function

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, definite-integrals, fourier-series

I need to find the complex Fourier series of this function, and I'm having problems  calculating these integers:

$$|a|<1$$

$$x\in [-\pi,\pi]$$

$$f(x)=\frac{1-a\cos(x)}{1-2a\cos(x)+a^2}$$

$$a_0=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1-a\cos(x)}{1-2a\cos(x)+a^2}dx$$

$$b_n=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1-a\cos(x)}{1-2a\cos(x)+a^2}\sin(nx)dx$$

Please help me on this integers, I can't solve them! I have no clue how to start... To get the complex serie....
Thanks